# unable to connect to jmeter proxy with android 4.4.2

Tags: android, jmeter

I am connecting the android device to jmeter 2.12 using HTTP Test script recorder and also configured the host ip in wifi. but when i am launching the url in browser of android device it says Unable to connect to proxy. Can we actually load test the hybrid android application which are sending https request with jmeter. please suggest

Answer (score 0):

As per [Load Testing Mobile Apps. But Made Easy. guide](http://blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy)

> Note that Android supports only HTTP proxy. If your application uses an HTTPS connection, then you may use an additional application that performs with HTTPS proxing

So if you need to record HTTPS traffic I think that you need to install an application which can proxy HTTPS, for instance [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid)